# GridView footer not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to display a total in the GridView footer - nothing unusual there. I've followed the example on the Microsoft website, but it's not working:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTimeOverview" DataSourceID="sdsTimeOverview" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true" CssClass="gridview" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DateTimeAdded" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DateTimeAdded" HeaderText="Time" DataFormatString="{0:HH:mm}" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TimeToAdd" HeaderText="Mins Allocated" />
            </Columns>    
        </asp:GridView>
```

Code:

```
protected void gvTimeOverview_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        totalMins += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "TimeToAdd"));
    }
    else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Totals:";
        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = totalMins.ToString();
        e.Row.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
}
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Is condition `if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)` ever passed?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the *not working part* ? Does `totalMins` have any value while debug ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972833.aspx

Comment: sll - no, a break point on that line is not hit, but I don't know why. Niranjan - that is the guide I followed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Event handler is not attached.

```
<asp:GridView 
       ID="gvTimeOverview" 
       DataSourceID="sdsTimeOverview" 
       AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
       ShowFooter="true" 
       CssClass="gridview" 
       runat="server"
       onrowdatabound="gvTimeOverview_RowDataBound">
....
```